# GitHub site not loading on Chrome and Chromium on Ubuntu 18.10

Tags: google-chrome, internet, chromium, 18.10, github

When I want open the GitHub site I get this error:

```
 This site can’t be reached github.com took too long to respond.
 Try:
 Checking the connection
 Checking the proxy and the firewall
 ERR_TIMED_OUT
```

#### Fixes I tried

1. Using Chromium instead
2. Installing Chrome from snap
3. Installing from Ubuntu repository

but it's not fixed.

#### Other Notes:

1. GitHub works on Firefox and on cURL
2. On the same network GitHub pages work on Android Chrome.
3. Also on Ubuntu 18.04 I had this problem too.